# Making multiple operator<<() definition for a single class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, compile-time, stream-operators

So basically this is what I want to make:

```
void someMethod() {
    StreamClass streamClass{};

    streamClass << "Something" << "\n"; //do something
    streamClass.doA << "Something" << "\n"; //do another thing
    streamClass.doB << "Something" << "\n"; //do something else

    //If the first one is impossible, what about this?
    streamClass << "Something" << "\n"; //do something
    streamClass::doA << "Something" << "\n"; //do another thing
    streamClass::doB << "Something" << "\n"; //do something else

    //Or this?
    streamClass<enumA> << "Something" << "\n"; //do something
    streamClass<enumB> << "Something" << "\n"; //do another thing
    streamClass<enumC> << "Something" << "\n"; //do something else
}
```

Header file:

```
class StreamClass {
public:
    StreamClass(); //Init class
    //... and many other things
    template<typename T>
    StreamClass& operator<<(T t) {
        //... do something that uses data and t
    }
    //And do something here?
protected:
    Data data; //some data owned by this object
};
```

So, is there anyway to do something like that? And how to do it in the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is perfectly viable, as long as you make `doA` and `doB` members of `StreamClass`, give them a reference to the `StreamClass` instance that has them (during construction) and make them implement `operator<<`.

At the end, the types of `doA` and `doB` should hold a reference/pointer to `StreamClass` or `StreamClass::Data`. Consider forbidding copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

---

The second option is syntactically valid, but requires `doA` and `doB` to be static, which ultimately makes it impossible to have two `StreamClass` instances at the same time with different behavior.

The last way is syntactically invalid, given that `streamClass` is not a variable template.